# Get values of multiple columns each on it's own row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 values:

```
id | name | v1   | v2   | v3 
---+------+------+------+---
 1 | John | 6    | null | 7
 2 | Jack | null | 5    | 9
```

Is there a simple way to get the different values from `v1`, `v2` and `v3` each on it's own row, preferably without the `null's`? So the result would be:

```
id | name | value
---+------+------
 1 | John |  6
 1 | John |  7
 2 | Jack |  5
 2 | Jack |  9
```

The only query I came up with is one with 3 subqueries, so maybe there is a better way to do this:

```
SELECT id, name, value 
FROM (
  (SELECT id, name, v1 value FROM table WHERE v1 IS NOT NULL)
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, name, v2 value FROM table WHERE v2 IS NOT NULL)
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, name, v3 value FROM table WHERE v3 IS NOT NULL)
) V
GROUP BY id, name, value
```

Comment: Note that enumerated column names *can* be indicative of suboptimal design

Answer (score 1):

you don't need subquery and group by - just UNION ALL is enough

```
SELECT id, name, v1 value FROM table WHERE v1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, v2 value FROM table WHERE v2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, v3 value FROM table WHERE v3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, if you start with a table design like this, then the problem becomes trivial...

```
| id | v_id | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |    1 |     6 | 
|  1 |    3 |     7 |
|  2 |    2 |     5 | 
|  2 |    3 |     9 |
```